# what happens if we remove resconfigs from build.gradle file?

Tags: android, build.gradle

My build.gradle file is written like below :

```
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 16
        versionName "0.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
    }
```

When I try build code, it is giving below error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Cannot filter assets for multiple densities using SDK build tools 21 or later. 
 Consider using apk splits instead.
```

When I remove resConfigs from defaultConfig , Above error is removed and Code is built successfully and apk is generated.

Is this apk will run on all the devices, as it was working previously ?
Or am I doing any mistake ?

Please suggest me if there is any other solution. I just want to maintain single apk only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing will happen just remove it.. it no use.

Comment: Thanks. @Sagar what was actually causing the above error. On my old system, I did not see this error.

Comment: and change the compile & target sdk version to 23 and used runtime permission if you want to maintain your single apk in any platform, bcz its no work in marshmellow

Answer (score 0):

Indeed removing the resConfigs line from the build.gradle file will create an APK file that runs on the same devices as before. It might just be a bit bigger because more resources get included. If you want to shrink the APK to similar levels as before you might add a "splits" section after the "defaultConfigs" section:

```
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
    }
}
```

This will include resources with the same densities you used before and leave out the other densities.